# Can I RDP into my local Windows 10 PC while it is connected to a VPN?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop

I've seen the answer to be "no" before, but there's got to be a way to do it.

Basically I have a pc here at home. I work from home. So, I frequently connect into my work's VPN on this pc. Sometimes I want to use Microsoft Remote Desktop from my phone (happens to be an iPhone currently) to remote into this pc, but I really want to be able to do this while it is connected to the VPN.

I'm very willing to get my hands dirty - there's got to be a way. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you want to RDP from your phone, across the Internet, to your home PC, or are you using work's Wifi or something?  Can you currently RDP to the computer, from your phone, when it's NOT attached to the work VPN?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I can RDP to the PC just fine with my phone when not connected to wifi. I do this while at my home - so both the pc and phone are on my home wifi. I'm wanting to be able to be, say, upstairs in my home on my phone, RDP'd into my PC here at home, and do this while the PC is also VPN'd into work. If I have to go over the Internet to finally arrive at the PC while it is VPN'd I'd be willing to see how well it works. I just don't know what the implications are in terms of the VPN, like if that would even be allowed by our network.

Comment: Have you tested it ? And it doesn't work what steps have you tried

Comment: Which VPN client are you using?  The stuff built into Windows?  When you're connected to your work VPN, does all network/Internet traffic flow through work?

Comment: @SeanClt yes I've tested. I use the working connection when not on VPN and it fails to connect if the PC is connected on VPN. Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am using Cisco anyconnect. And your traffic question - I don't know, but I'd love to learn how to figure that out! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your VPN, how it's configured, and whether you're allowed to change this configuration. The concept you're describing is [split tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling). Some (many?) workplaces disable split tunneling (or at least, it's against their policy) for security reasons.

Comment: I know about split tunneling. However, I am hoping this is some kind of solution I could implement with my home network that would allow me access to the PC via RDP while it is on VPN. I am hoping there's just some kind of solution I might be able implement in my home network.

Answer (score 0):

VPN Settings are inherited from the VPN Server, normally if you need an exception let's say to RDP ports you would have to ask your IT department to make these exceptions

*for security reasons it might be difficult to have a sound justification why you need to leave you work computer VPN logged in and while you are not at your Desktop.

### Changing RDP Port(might not work but if you are going to forward RDP Port it helps to have non default for security reasons)

1. [Change RDP port](https://kb.iweb.com/entries/23462112-Change-the-Remote-Desktop-Connection-port-to-your-Windows-Server) from default 3389 to in a higher range like 65000
2. Try connecting locally from another PC on LAN to see if this works

### Workaround

Use Software like TeamViewer or even WebEx, There are smart phones apps for these

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I happen to work in our IT department :) however, I am a developer and not as much on the infrastructure/network side of things.